# Generate word 2003 document

Tags: xml, ms-word

I have data in XHTML and plain text in SQL Server 2005. I need to generate a Word 2003 document from this data. I was thinking of using Word XML 2003 to do this. Are there any good tools to generate Word XML 2003?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use XML with Word 2003 you can use a SDK from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214923.aspx

Since you already have the data in an XML format, you could use the following tool to create an XSLT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212886.aspx. This tool should be included in the SDK.

Please let me know if you need further help with this.